# Get value of an element of a list

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need to access the value of an element in a list in a different class. Here is how it goes:

In class DocumentManager.java:

```
    Domain.Form form = new Domain.Form();
    Services.Form wsForm = new Services.Form();
```

What I have not been able to do is to assign the value of versionLabel in the similar manner. I think this is because "version" is a List in "form" and String in "wsForm". I would want something like the following:

```
    wsForm.setVersionLabel(form.getVersions().getLabel());
```

"label" has a String value. I want to assign that to versionLabel in "wsForm".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How many objects do you have in that `versions` list in Form object ? Is it one or many ?

Comment: wsForm.setVersionLabel(form.getVersions().get(0).getLabel()); you can get first version label like this

Comment: @Arkantos At least one, and this keeps on increasing as the forms are modified.

Comment: @Naman get(0) is fetching the first element, right?

Comment: And you always need to show the label from the most recent version is it ?

Comment: I already mentioned that it shows first element. What do you want to show? All label or latest?

Comment: @Arkantos At this moment I do not know whether it will be either first or last. This is what is complicating the matter. I know get(0) will fetch the first element. Could I do get(last) or something like that?

Comment: @Naman I did not properly notice your comment. How would I show the latest label?

Comment: Yes you can get the last element.. You just need to pass the index of last element. Have a look at the answer I just posted

Comment: form.getVersions().get(form.getVersions().size()-1).getLabel()) also check null and size before applying this if there is chance of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `form.getVersions()` will returns `List<Version>` so you can't call below code:

```
wsForm.setVersionLabel(form.getVersions().getLabel());
```

If you want you can use following:

```
wsForm.setVersionLabel(form.getVersions().get(yourIndex).getLabel());// change index for object which you want
```

**Note:** You have to make sure which Version object's label you want to set in wsForm, In the example its just setting for first object. And make sure `form.getVersions()` is not null nor empty.

---

For last element

```
form.getVersions().get(form.getVersions().size()-1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There will be at least one element in the list. I know get(0) will give me the first element. What if I require the last element and I do not know how many elements are there?

Comment: See the answer for details

Answer (score 1):

You are working with a List and therefore you have to call

```
wsForm.setVersionLabel(form.getVersions().get(/index here/).getLabel());
```

What you were doing is calling a non-existing method for Lists on a List. In this way you can get to a certain Version in the list, and on this Version object you can call your getLabel method.

However, the real question here is, what index do you need? Or, put otherwise, are there multiple objects in the `versions` list? Because if not, you are overcomplicating things for yourself here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There will be at least one element in the list. I know get(0) will give me the first element. What if I require the last element and I do not know how many elements are there?

Comment: You can use the size() method for lists. `wsForm.setVersionLabel(form.getVersions().get(form.getVersions().size()-1).getLabel());` I think it's very helpful for you to check out the Java documentation on Lists https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, that your `versions` increase every time someone modifies your form and if you want to get the version label of the most recent edit, you can do something like this.

```
int recentIndex = form.getVersions().size()-1;
wsForm.setVersionLabel(form.getVersions().get(recentIndex).getLabel());
```

As you're adding versions to list, the most recent version is the last version in your list, so get the label from that version